# How to Put Dotted Border on selected Image, Like We see in Photo Editor in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making a photo editor and I got stuck here, if anyone can help me  How to Achieve this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use this package, [dotted_border](https://pub.dev/packages/dotted_border):

```
DottedBorder(
    color: _isSelected ? Colors.black : Colors.transparent,
    strokeWidth: 1,
    child: FlutterLogo(size: 148),
)
```